# How to configure jboss logging in version 7.1.3

Tags: logging, jboss7.x, slf4j

What's the best way to configure logging in jboss, I've tried 2 approach (both failed):
1.) Use jboss built-in, according to some articles I just need to add dependency on slf4j-api as provided scope:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

*The problem here is no logs where shown in eclipse console.

2.) Use logback, so I excluded slf4j and impl in jboss-deployment-structure.xml and I include slf4j/logback dependencies on my war project. The logging works but I there's a prefix DATE LOG_LEVEL, the I think came from jboss.

I found something weird, when I include log4j jars logging work but only for INFO level, debug still doesn't show up.

Other info:
I'm injecting the log from a producer:

```
@Inject
protected org.slf4j.Logger log;

@Produces
public Logger createLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
}
```

Console logger settings:

```
<console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
    </formatter>
</console-handler>
```

I found something abnormal:
1.) I created a new ear project and logging works as expected.
2.) In the war project it fails, but if I add jboss-deployment-structure.xml and add exclusion to:

```
<module name="org.slf4j" />
<module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
```

That's when INFO logging works.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Using slf4j should work fine with the subsystem configuration. Do you see any log messages in the eclipse console?

Comment: hi James, No unusual log only the INFO and DEBUG message from Jboss which I think must be from before the logging subsystem kicks in. Then when the subsystem starts I can only see INFO messages from my application. Do I need to configure something? btw note that I'm injecting the logger: @Inject protected org.slf4j.Logger log;

Comment: Did you only edit the logging.properties file? If so you also need to edit the standalone.xml (assuming standalone here) to allow the console-handler to log at DEBUG level and root-logger or define your own logger.

Comment: Hi James, yes I already edited standalone.xml. I've set root-logger level to DEBUG.

Comment: Did you set the console-handler to DEBUG as well?

Comment: JamesR.Perkins, yes. I've set it to debug. I've updated my post above with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case is my project's dependency to kettle-engine jar. After I removed it everything worked well. I'm not sure what's in kettle that's causing the problem though.